# Add images dynamically intoa listview from the gallery/ by using camera using xamarin forms

Tags: image, listview, xamarin.forms, contacts

I am building a contacts app and when i add a contact into the listview i need to add the image of the person along with name and mobile number

Comment: What is your question?  This is just a list of requirements.

Comment: As @Jason said your question is totally blank on what you tried, Issues you faced. Moreover from what you have asked all you need to do is bind the correct properties of ViewModel. Please add more details to your query.